# Scaling images as soon as screen size changes

Tags: css, image, scale

I need to scale my images as soon as screen / browser size changes, keeping ratio and position.

I know about width: 100%, max-width; height: auto - and so on - but none of it is what I'm looking for - it really has to be exact to my line: start scaling images at once, when browser window even is minimized to 99%

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to show you:

```
<div class="foo">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RYjIHr9.png">
</div>

<style>
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .foo img {width: 100px;}
}
</style>
```

Live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/20t24pqh/2/ - try to resize the browser window

Comment: This is about the thing I always do, but it doesn't resize anything before really necessary. For me, it's necessary from the moment anyone resizes the browser - thnx

Answer (score 0):

what is your code? I think using bootstrap will help you it has an img-responsive class. that will make your image responsive to the windowsize. please refer http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Is not much coding in html, it's all happening i css - my web where I'm trying to make this work is: http://www.kjellerup.biz/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary offers a nice responsive support for images.
See: http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_create_images_for_responsive_design

Comment: Looks really nice but isn't it "just" scaling like you easily can do width the above mentioned? Even if the image is smaller as the browser window, I want it to scale as soon as you start minimizing (or scaling for instance).

Comment: Not sure I understand what's missing.
Check out this example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/fh9njeLm/3/
Specifically here, if you down-scale the image will be resized and if you up-scale in some point Cloudinary will fetch a larger image to retain quality.